# Ensuring same dimensions in Python

Tags: python, numpy

The dimensions of `P` is `(2,3,3)`. But the dimensions of `M` is `(3,3)`. How can I ensure that both `P` and `M` have the same dimensions  i.e. `(2,3,3)`.

```
import numpy as np
P=np.array([[[128.22918457, 168.52413295, 209.72343319],
        [129.01598287, 179.03716051, 150.68633749],
        [131.00688309, 187.42601593, 193.68172751]],

       [[ 64.11459228,  84.26206648, 104.86171659],
        [ 64.50799144,  89.51858026,  75.34316875],
        [ 65.50344155,  93.71300796,  96.84086375]]])

for x in range(0,2):
    M=P[x]+1
    print(M)
```

Comment: By changing at least one of the arrays?!

Comment: If you write `M = P[0]`, how should `M` have the same dimension as `P`? Can you show an example of how you imagine this to be the case?

Comment: Why you used `M=P+1`? Just for making the shapes equal?? it will affect and change values of `M`, not just working on the shape. What is the main need?

Comment: I want ```M``` to take ```P[0]``` and add 1 to each element. Then I want ```M``` to take ```P[1]``` and add 1 to each element. The resulting ```M``` should store the resulting new ```(3,3)``` matrices and thus, ```M``` will have the same dimensions as ```P```.

Comment: @user18773282 So the question is not related to changing dimensions or ensuring the shapes are the same and is about adding `1` to `P` and storing in a new variable `M`, which can be done very easily by [AboAmmar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72658478/13394817).

Comment: Sounds like you are confused about what happens in a loop.  Your loop adds 1 to a (3,3) subarray of `P`, and assigns it to the variable `M`.  It goes it again, again assigning that to `M` (and throwing away the previous result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
M = P + 1
```

and that ensures `M` and `P` have the same dimensions.

Comment: In this case, the for loop is not necessary anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need this and for what (why you have tried to use `M = P + 1` for making the shape equal?). But, you can ensure they have same shapes using `assert`:

```
assert a.shape == b.shape
```

It will get error when the shapes are not the same, so you can be sure that dimensions are the same if it didn't stuck and get error.