# Storing values in a for loop in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to store values at each iteration through a for loop. The current and desired outputs are attached.

```
import numpy as np
from array import *
ar = []

A=np.array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]],

       [[ 10,  11, 12],
        [ 13,  14,  15],
        [ 16,  17,  18]]])

for x in range(0,2):
    B=A[x]+1
    ar.append(B) 
print(ar)
```

The current output is

```
[array([[ 2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10]]), array([[11, 12, 13],
       [14, 15, 16],
       [17, 18, 19]])]
```

The desired output is

```
array([[[ 2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9,  10]],

       [[11, 12, 13],
        [14, 15, 16],
        [17, 18, 19]]])
```

Comment: It is the same as your previous question. Just use `B =A+1`. why not?
if you want using loops, at the end of loop use `np.array(ar)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ensuring same dimensions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72658374/ensuring-same-dimensions-in-python)

Comment: current output is a list, which is reasonable for loop.  `np.array(ar)` makes a single array from that list.  Just as you do with making `A`.

Comment: The answer to the previous question brought the desired result. It is unclear why this is being asked again in a different way, but the existing solution is ignored. If the problem wasn't previously resolved, the new question should make it clear why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ali_Sh's comment is correct, and the usage here is simply `b = a + 1`, and that's that.

I will assume you are dumbing down some complicated use case which requires looping, so here is your code in a working form:

```
import numpy as np


a = np.array([[[1, 2, 3],
               [4, 5, 6],
               [7, 8, 9]],

              [[10, 11, 12],
               [13, 14, 15],
               [16, 17, 18]]])

ar = []
for x in range(0,2):
    b = a[x, :] + 1
    ar.append(b)

print(np.stack(ar))
```